# How to store editable define constant web settings in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, constants

I'm creating simple web application using php. And there is basic constant settings in (config.php) like:

```
define('SITE_NAME', 'Site A');
define('SITE_URL', 'https://example.com');
define('SITE_EMAIL', 'test@example.com');
define('SENDGRID_API', 'G.6786jka9769fhgg45479989hjvh');
```

And calling this file almost every page. Is it possible to store this value in mysql and it's editable via web interface for admin? If yes, how to do it? So that i don't need to connect to db for everytime using this constant. If i'm not mistaken, some settings from wordpress is using something like this.

Comment: Answer to your question is __yes__.

Comment: Of course. I can put together an example for you in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your solution create a table like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `settings`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `settings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_option` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `site_value` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
COMMIT;
```

Needs 4 files:  index.php, db.php, create.php, update.php

**db.php**

```
function connect()
{
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=update;';

    try{
        return new PDO($dsn, 'root', '');
    }catch( \Exception $e ){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>


<htmL>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Test UPDATING records in PHP</title>
</head>
<div>

    <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['success'])){
          echo $_SESSION['success'];
      }elseif(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
          echo $_SESSION['error'];
      }
      //clearing all session values
      session_unset();
    ?>

    <h2>Create New Site Option / Setting</h2>

    <form action="create.php" method="POST">
       Site Option: <input type='text' name='site_option' size='12' value=''>
        Site Value: <input type='text' name='site_value' size='12' value=''>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>

<?php
    require_once('db.php');

    $pdo = connect();

    if( $pdo instanceof \PDO ){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM settings";

        $dbh = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        var_dump($dbh);
        $dbh->execute();

        foreach($dbh as $row){
                echo "<div style='padding-bottom:1em;' class='datarow'>";
                echo "<input type='text' name='site_option' size='12' value='{$row['site_option']}'>";
                echo "<input type='text' name='site_value' size='3' value='{$row['site_value']}'>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' size='3' value='{$row['id']}'>";
                echo "<button onClick='updateValues(this);'>Update Option</button>";
                echo "</div>";

            //define the constant
            if (!defined($row['site_option'])) {
                define( strtoupper($row['site_option']),$row['site_value']);
            }
        }

        // To see all constants , uncomment if you need to see them for testing
        // print_r(get_defined_constants(true));


    }else{
        //echo $pdo->getMessage();
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateValues(obj){
        let datarow = $(obj).closest('.datarow');
        //("input[name='quantity']").val()
        console.log($('input[name="author"]', datarow).val());

        $.post( "update.php", { site_option: $('input[name="site_option"]', datarow).val(),
                                site_value:  $('input[name="site_value"]', datarow).val(),
                                id: $('input[name="id"]', datarow).val()
                                //id: $(obj).data('parentid')

            }
        ).done(function( data ) {
           if( ! $.isEmptyObject( data.error ) ) {
                alert( 'error' + data.error);
           }else{
               //success
               alert( 'Success: ' + data.success );
               location.reload();
           }

        });
    }
</script>
</htmL>
```

**create.php**

```
session_start();
require_once('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['site_option']) && isset($_POST['site_value'])){

    //Todo: do some sort of validation / sanity checking (dont trust user input)
    $site_option = $_POST['site_option'];
    $site_value =  $_POST['site_value'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO settings ( id, site_option, site_value ) VALUES ( NULL, :site_option, :site_value )";

    $pdo = connect();

    $dbh = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    try{
        $dbh->execute( [
            ':site_option'    => $site_option,
            ':site_value'       => $site_value
        ] );
        $_SESSION['success'] = 'Successful creation of new record';
        header("Location: index.php");

    }catch( \Exception $e ){
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Error creating new entry';
        //echo json_encode( [ 'error' => $e->getMessage() ] );
    }
}
```

**update.php**

```
require_once('db.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    //Todo: do some sort of validation / sanity checking (dont trust user input)
    $sql = "UPDATE settings SET site_option=:site_option, site_value=:site_value WHERE id=:id";
    $pdo = connect();
    $dbh = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    try{
        $dbh->execute( [
            ':site_option'    => $_POST['site_option'],
            ':site_value'       => $_POST['site_value'],
            ':id'        => $_POST['id']
        ] );
        echo json_encode( [ 'success' => 'Record updated.' . $_POST['site_option'] ] );
    }catch( \Exception $e ){
        echo json_encode( ['error' => 'Error updating the record' ]);
        //echo json_encode( [ 'error' => $e->getMessage() ] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes please, how to set/get the values?